# RFID scanner doesn't scan afterwards

Tags: python, raspberry-pi3

I am very new to coding and I'm working on this project that I have no idea why is it not running as expected. I am sorry if I'm not posting this correctly because this is my first time posting on stackoverflow. Pardon my English if there's any point where I didn't explain it correctly.

This is a project supposed to be a security system one, where we work with RFID Scanner, Camera, LED, Servo and PIR Sensor.

The conditions are as, when the time is 7am to 11pm, the pir sensor would be off and when time is 11pm onwards to 7am in the morning, the PIR sensor and camera will be turned on. Where during anytime, as long as the number of people in the house is = 0 (determined by the RFID), the camera and PIR Sensor would turn on too.

I haven't got a chance to even test out my code's logic, because when I tried to run the code, an error occurs at the loop part. "Scan a registered card to skip registration" would print and "checkpoint" would print, but afterward the code just stops there. It is supposed to be listening to the RFID scanner to read for scans, but when I tapped my card on the RFID scanner there was no response. And my code just dies there. As I'm very new to coding and python, I don't know where the errors could be. Would appreciate the help given!!

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from time import sleep
import sys
import requests
from datetime import datetime
from mfrc522 import SimpleMFRC522 #RFID
import os
import pygame, sys
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.image import MIMEImage
from pygame.locals import *
import pygame.camera

width = 640
height = 480

#initialise pygame
pygame.init()
pygame.camera.init()
cam = pygame.camera.Camera("/dev/video0",(width,height))
no=0


GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)

GPIO.setup(24,GPIO.OUT) #LED
GPIO.setup(26,GPIO.OUT) #Servo
GPIO.setup(17,GPIO.IN) #PIR Sensor

current_time =datetime.now() #Current time

sleep(5)

reader = SimpleMFRC522() #RFID reader
auth = []
in_house =[]
p = open("presentlist.txt","a+")
p = open("presentlist.txt","r+")
present = 0

PIR_state =0 

PWM=GPIO.PWM(26,50) #Set 50hz PWM output at GPIO26
PWM.start(12) #To edit to actual 3oclock (Locked)


fromaddr = "pythonprogramtest123@gmail.com" # change the email address accordingly
toaddr = "pythonprogramtest123@gmail.com" # Same email
#password: abcdefgpython
mail = MIMEMultipart()
 
mail['From'] = fromaddr
mail['To'] = toaddr
mail['Subject'] = "Attachment"
body = "Unusual movement detected"


print('Door Locked') 
print("Hold card near the reader to register it in the database.")
print("Registration up to 10 cards")
print("Scan a registered card to skip registration")

for count in range (0,11):
    print("checkpoint1")
    id = reader.read_id()
    id = str(id)
    f = open("authlist.txt", "a+")
    f = open("authlist.txt", "r+")
    print("checkpoint2")
    if f.mode == "r+":
        auth=f.read()
    if id not in auth:
        f.write(id)
        f.write('\n')
        f.close()
        pos = auth.count('\n')
        print("New card with UID", id, "detected: registered as entry #",pos)
        count = count +1
    else:
        number = auth.split('\n')
        pos = number.index(id)
        print("Card with UID", id, "already registered as entry #", pos)
        count = 11
        break
    

while (True):
    id = reader.read_id()
    id = str(id)
    f = open("authlist.txt", "a+")
    f = open("authlist.txt", "r+")
    if current_time.hour >= 7 or current_time.hour <= 23 or present == 0: #awake or nobody in house
        #RFID is on
        if f.mode == "r+":
            auth=f.read()
        if id in auth and id not in in_house:
            p.write(id)
            p.write('\n')
            p.close()
            present = in_house.count('\n')
            print("Recognition successful \n Allowing Access")
            PWM.start(1) #Servo to actual 12 o clock position (Unlocking)
            print("Door unlocked for 30 seconds. Tap once more to change to 1 minute")
            if f.mode == "r+":
                auth=f.read()
            if id in auth:
                print("Unlocking door for 1 minute")
                sleep(60)
                PWM.start(12) #To edit to actual 3oclock (Locked)
                f.close()
        
            else: #no tap detected
                sleep(30)
                PWM.start(12) #To edit to actual 3oclock (Locked)
                f.close()
                break

        elif id in auth and id in in_house:
            p.remove(id)
            print("Recognition successful \n Allowing Access")
            PWM.start(1) #Servo to actual 12 o clock position (Unlocking)
            print("Door unlocked for 30 seconds. Tap once more to change to 1 minute")
            if f.mode == "r+":
                auth=f.read()
            if id in auth:
                print("Unlocking door for 1 minute")
                sleep(60)
                PWM.start(12) #To edit to actual 3oclock (Locked)
                f.close()
        
            else: #no tap detected
                sleep(30)
                PWM.start(12) #To edit to actual 3oclock (Locked)
                f.close()
                break
        else:
            print("Card not recognised \n Access Denied")
           
        break
    
    elif current_time.hour < 7 or current_time.hour > 23: #sleeping
        id = reader.read_id()
        id = str(id)
        f = open("authlist.txt", "a+")
        f = open("authlist.txt", "r+")
        #RFID is on
        if f.mode == "r+":
            auth=f.read()
        if id in auth:
            print("Recognition successful \n Allowing Access")
            PWM.start(1) #Servo to actual 12 o clock position (Unlocking)
            print("Door unlocked for 30 seconds. Tap once more to change to 1 minute")
            if f.mode == "r+":
                auth=f.read()
            if id in auth:
                print("Unlocking door for 1 minute")
                sleep(60)
                PWM.start(12) #To edit to actual 3oclock (Locked)
        
            else: #no tap detected
                sleep(30)
                PWM.start(12) #To edit to actual 3oclock (Locked)
                break
        else:
            print("Card not recognised \n Access Denied")
        break


        #Camera
        if GPIO.input(17): #read a HIGH i.e. motion is detected

            #LED Blink
            GPIO.output(24,1)
            sleep(1)
            GPIO.output(24,0)
            sleep(1)
            GPIO.output(24,1)
            sleep(1)
            GPIO.output(24,0)
            
            if PIR_state==0:
                print('detected HIGH i.e. motion detected')
                PIR_state=1
                
                #Camera
                cam.start() #start
                image = cam.get_image() #take pic
                cam.stop()
                no = no + 1
                saved_img=pygame.image.save(windowSurfaceObj,'picture' + "{:03d}".format(no) + '.jpg')

                #Thingspeak
                print("Updating Thingpseak")
                resp = requests.get("GET https://api.thingspeak.com/update?api_key=PQ44ZG5JR49ABODY&field1=0")
                #Email
                def sendMail(data):
                    mail.attach(MIMEText(body, 'plain'))
                    print (data)
                    dat='%s.jpg'%data
                    print (dat)
                    attachment = open(dat, 'rb')
                    image=MIMEImage(attachment.read())
                    attachment.close()
                    mail.attach(image)
                    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
                    server.starttls()
                    server.login(fromaddr, "abcdefgpython")
                    text = mail.as_string()
                    server.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddr, text)
                    server.quit()
                
        else: #read a LOW i.e. no motion is detected
            if PIR_state==1:
                print('detected LOW i.e. no motion detected')
                PIR_state=0
        sleep(1)
        print("...")
        break
    
    sleep(2)
```

Comment: Have you tried adding some simple print statements at critical points in your code low, so you see where the code has got to? Or add logging. And remove one of the lines `f=open...` because you don’t need both.

Comment: yes, i've tried adding simple print statements. "checkpoint1" would print but "checkpoint2" does not. even after I scanned a card on the rfid scanner, there was no reaction.